# How to perform SQL batch inserts in Entity Framework Core 6 using C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have the following code to insert applications to a table:

```
public async Task<Application> InsertApplicationAsync(List<Application> applications)
{
     foreach (var app in applications)
     {
            var application = new Application();
            application.Id = Id;
            application.Identifier = Identifier;
            await _context.AddAsync(application);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
}
```

Is it possible to insert in bulk in EF Core 6?

Comment: Use extensions.

Comment: 1) Call `SaveChanges` once and ef core will batch some sql statements together. 2) use `SqlBulkCopy`. 3) define a TVP and `insert () .... select * from @p0`.

Comment: tl;dr move that `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` after the `foreach` finished.

Comment: Could you please share a sample solution?

Answer (score 1):

use `AddRange` to insert Bulk data at once code as follows.

```
   public async Task<Application> InsertApplicationAsync(List<Application> applications)
    {
        var Data = applications.Select(App => new Application
        {
            Id=App.Id,
            Name=App.Name,
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //....
        }).ToList();
        await _context.AddRangeAsync(Data);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Can use package Z entity frame work but it's not fully Open source. for now `BulkInsert` is Free

package:`<PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore" Version="6.22.3" />`

code as follows

```
   public async Task<Application> InsertApplicationAsync(List<Application> applications)
    {
        var Data = applications.Select(App => new Application
        {
            Id = App.Id,
            Name = App.Name,
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //....
        }).ToList();
        _context.BulkInsert(Data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

From docs:

```
context.BulkInsert(entities);                 context.BulkInsertAsync(entities);
context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities);         context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities);         // Upsert
context.BulkInsertOrUpdateOrDelete(entities); context.BulkInsertOrUpdateOrDeleteAsync(entities); // Sync
context.BulkUpdate(entities);                 context.BulkUpdateAsync(entities);
context.BulkDelete(entities);                 context.BulkDeleteAsync(entities);
context.BulkRead(entities);                   context.BulkReadAsync(entities);
context.BulkSaveChanges();                    context.BulkSaveChangesAsync();
```

See usage example here: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/master/EFCore.BulkExtensions.Tests/EFCoreBulkTestAsync.cs